# Unable to use remote stored procedures in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

My DBA has create a stored procedure on the production instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 and granted me access to it to build a Web Forms UI.

utility.dbo.getPlanetInfo

However, once connected to the database, I don't see the stored procedure in the 'Stored Procedures' folder in the Server Explorer, thus I can't create my SQDataSource, since the stored procedure option within that wizard is greyed out.

What do I have to tell the DBA to do so that the stored procedure is available to me?

Comment: What database version are you using?

Comment: Ok, version isn't the problem at least. Have you successfully used other Procs in your app? Web or Forms by the way?

Comment: Web forms. Have not used stored procs in VS10, but my understanding is the stored proc on the server should be available to me. Obviously I can't authoer my own, since the stored proc is ALL that has been made available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that you *really do* have permission to access the proc, try doing it without using the server explorer - just drag a SQLDataSource onto the page and configure the connection through the smart tag?

Should give you a drop-down of the procs available to you and if you see none, I'd suggest going back to your DBA to check the connection and permissions. Also, try calling the proc from Management Studio - if you can't do that then you know you don't have permissions.

Comment: Correct, it was a permissions issue.